# How to start reading file after designated number of lines

Tags: c#, file, stream

I've got the following text files. The task is simple: ignore the ALL the lines in blue and START READING the file at the place indicated by the arrow. (I posted a question similar but people's replies weren't working so i decided to combine the answers and ask properly this time)

[image]

here is my code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName));

            int i = 1;

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                if (i > 8)
                    textBox1.Text = sr.ReadLine(); // As soon as i get to the arrow         (8th line, I want to display the line in the textbox in my application.)

                sr.ReadLine();
                i++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My Problem: I dont think my while loop is right at all. When I try to display what the while loop contains, nothing pops up in the textbox. Secondly, THIS is the output I get with the code above:

It's clearly wrong, I dont even know where 0 subtotals and 671etc come from.

[image]

WHAT I expect the output to be is the first arrowed line: "1 MANDT CLIENT etc etc "

Thanks guys

Comment: Are you selecting the right file?

Comment: Is there anyway you could share the file on git hub or some other share? I remember reading the first post and would like to help.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @jcwrequests let me know if u still want to help ill upload

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could skip the `StreamReader` and simply use `File.ReadAllLines` with a `Skip()` tacked on:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName).Skip(8).ToArray();

textBox1.Lines = lines;
```

This assumes the TextBox is set up for MultiLine (`textBox1.MultiLine = true;`).

**Additional Explanation**

The LINQ query above will return an `System.Linq.Enumerable.SkipIterator<string>`; the `.ToArray()` at the end turns that back into an array, which is needed to assign it to `textBox1.Lines`, as that property expects a `string[]`.

Comment: let me try that.. also wat array is it going to when it states ".ToArray()"

Comment: @user2788405 - `var lines` will be the array that `.ToArray()` creates.  The `.ToArray()` might be unnecessary, since `ReadAllLines` returns an array.

Comment: @user2788405 - `TextBox.Lines` expects a `string[]` (array), but the query without `.ToArray()` will return a `System.Linq.Enumerable.SkipIterator<string>`, which won't be implicitly converted.  The `.ToArray()` simply turns the result of the query into an array.

Comment: Pls check your email, I need a bit more clarification

Answer (score 2):

You keep reading until the end of the file, replacing the textbox's contents with every successive line.  If you really want *just* the first unskipped line, you'll need to break out of the loop:

```
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
  if (i > 8)
  {
    textBox1.Text = sr.ReadLine(); 
    break;
  }

  sr.ReadLine();
  i++;
}
```

Or if you want *all* unskipped lines,

```
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
  string text = sr.ReadLine();

  if (i > 8)
    textBox1.Text += text + "\n";

  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- You do not add text to Textbox. You rewrite it.
- You double read 2 lines and write only one if i > 8.

---

```
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    if (i > 8)
    {
        textBox1.Text += line + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    i++;
}
```

---

The simple way to read file is to use [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx)

```
string fileLines = File.ReadLines(ofd.FileName).Skip(8).Aggregate((current, next) => current + Environment.NewLine + next);
textBox1.Text = fileLines;
```